# How does the timing of the MPU9250 works?

Tags: arduino, imu

I am using an MPU9250 in my project and I am struggling with the timing domains of the various sensors.
Let's say I have the magnetometer ticking at 100Hz, the Gyroscope at 32kHz and the accelerometer at 4kHz. And I want to read the samples on a 20MHz SPI bus.

1) are all those clocks somehow locked together or free running separately?

2) who is the INT pin ticking for? (if it ticks as the `or` of all the sampling clocks, how do I know who it ticked for?)

3) how do I relate each sample to its clock tick (I need this information for filtering)? I see a lot of examples on github that read the sample fifo for all the sensors at once as if they had the same clock (a 21 bytes read starting at register `ACCEL_XOUT_H`) , do they read more than one time the same value of the slowest sensors?

Comment: the SPI bus does not read the data from the sensor directly ..... it obtains the data from the data register which is filled by the sensor circuitry ..... think of a fast conveyor belt  and a pile of rocks next to the conveyor belt ..... you pick up a rock and place it on the belt and the rock whizzes away from you at high speed .... then you pick up another rock and place it on the belt and away it goes ..... you do not have to match the speed of the conveyor belt in order to get the pile of rocks moved

Comment: There is an array of sensor values, when my MCU received a blip on the INT line, how does it know which register to go read?